# Preventing @Version From Reaching Maximum Value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I am implementing OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT, as described [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/07/30/jpa-20-concurrency-and-locking).

The main question is how to prevent the @version field from reaching its maximum value.

- Is there a way to handle this kind of
  exception?
- Is it possible to reset the @version field to 0
  in case of exception?
- is it possible to work with sequences
  to prevent this situation in the
  first place?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can try using using versioning with a timeStamp. Its max value is still a long way from now...

Comment: It's too big for my DB, because Derby uses a string of 14 places to represent a `TIMESTAMP`. There must be something like circular sequences to handle this concept correctly.